# How to upload mutiple images with one file up;oad like in facebook or orkut using asp.net(VB)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

How to upload mutiple images with one file up;oad like in facebook or orkut using asp.net(VB).

Comment: This is a good site for ASP.NET VB help. But you'll have to work on your questions. You should read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider 3rd party upload control. One of them is [Flajaxian File Uploader](http://flajaxian.com/).

Check out the [Video Tutorial](http://blog.bodurov.com/how-to-use-flajaxian-fileuploader-video-basics).